# Adding wait time in jmeter after every n number of threads

Tags: timer, jmeter

I have a Load test with following details:

```
Number of threads: 100
Ramp up time: 1 second

Thread group
|---HTTP Request1
```

I want the following:

```
100 threads to run in 1 sec
15 second delay
Then 100 threads run again 
15 secs delay
.
.
.
.
```

Any leads would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amend your test configuration as follows:

- [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) - set how many loops you want

  - [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)
  - [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) -> Action: `Pause` -> Duration: `15000`

    - [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) -> Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by: `100`

Comment: This worked. I had to make a few changes though. Thread group->no. of threads- 100, loop ->1. Set loop controller with loop count-> forever and added test Action and Synchronizing timer as mentioned. Thanks for the help